# Weird VIM colorscheme, I don't know what's going wrong in my configuration

Tags: linux, vim

I got a weird vim interface, please take a look at the following image:

[image]

How can I remove those red blocks?  It's not highlighted search.

What I did is switch from Gentoo to Arch, my ~/.vimrc remain unchanged.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is this the default color scheme or did you add it manually?

Comment: command `colorscheme' in vim returns 'default'

Comment: And changing to other scheme doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got [spell-checking](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27spell%27) enabled.

```
:set nospell
```

If you want to find who set `'spell'` (it's `off` by default), use:

```
:verbose set spell?
```

Comment: `bashrc` would likely be highlighted if this were spellchecking.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: Likely, yes. `:verbose set spell?` will tell for definite!

Comment: I have `nnoremap <F7> :<C-U>set spell! spell?<CR>` in my `.vimrc`, sometimes it's really handy to be able to toggle this feature.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: i use: if has('gui_running') , which only enables spell check in gVIM , normally i don't use a graphical vim interface , but i'll setup a shortcut for it , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax file that has those strings in it, telling the colorscheme to color them in some special way.  The colorscheme defines that special way to be utterly hideous.  :)

If you want that text highlighted, just differently, you'll need to edit your colorscheme.  If you don't want that text highlighted, you need to remove them from the syntax definition.

Unfortunately I don't know much about that stuff as I'm mostly happy with the defaults on Windows...